# Sudo Apache, with command line ? (not visudo)

Tags: shell-script, sudo, sudoedit

I have visudo-edited `/etc/sudoers` this way:

```
User_Alias  APACHE = www-data
Cmnd_Alias  FIREWALL = /sbin/iptables, /sbin/ifconfig, /sbin/route

APACHE  ALL = (ALL) NOPASSWD: FIREWALL
```

(To allow php running `iptables` cmd).

Is there a way to achieve the same, purely with terminal/tty/cmdline AND/OR root **shell script** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. You can just drop files into `/etc/sudoers.d` instead of editing the sudoers file itself:

```
cat > /etc/sudoers.d/apache <<EOF
User_Alias  APACHE = www-data
Cmnd_Alias  FIREWALL = /sbin/iptables, /sbin/ifconfig, /sbin/route

APACHE  ALL = (ALL) NOPASSWD: FIREWALL
EOF
chmod 440 /etc/sudoers.d/apache
```

And I guess if you were stuck with a really old `sudo` without support for the `sudoers.d` directory you could just concatenate that to `/etc/sudoers`:

```
if ! grep -q APACHE /etc/sudoers; then
cat >> /etc/sudoers <<EOF
User_Alias  APACHE = www-data
Cmnd_Alias  FIREWALL = /sbin/iptables, /sbin/ifconfig, /sbin/route

APACHE  ALL = (ALL) NOPASSWD: FIREWALL
EOF
fi
```

(The `if ! grep -q ...` is there to prevent concatenating this multiple times if the script is run more than once)